# Get error message from WPF BindingExpression

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Is there a way to get the error message from a programmatically generated binding? I only see e.g. the status "PathError", but not why it failed.

```
var binding = new Binding(path);
var expression = BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, TestProperty, binding);
if (expression.Status == BindingStatus.PathError)
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid binding!");   //why did the binding fail?
}
```

The dependency property is defined as

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(object), typeof(DashboardShape));
```

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The way to view `Binding` errors in WPF is to open the *Output Window* in Visual Studio. If they are not already being output, you can turn on the WPF Tracing to the Output Window from the *Options* dialog. You can find the options by following the path below:

> Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings

Once you have found the relevant options page, you can set the *Data Binding* setting to a value other than *Off*. *Warning* is a good level to use.

[image]

---

UPDATE >>>

`Binding` errors should be displayed in the *Output Window* regardless of how they were created, so it seems strange that you say there aren't any. However, I have another trick that I like to use when trying to debug `Binding` problems... the `DataBindingDebugConverter`:

```
public class DataBindingDebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value;
    }
}
```

Just add this `Converter` to the `Binding` that you are having problems with and then you'll be able to see what data bound values you have. Please note that this will *not* display `Binding` errors, but will help you with your `Binding` debugging.

Comment: I have already set it to Warning, but it is not shown (presumably because the binding is not set inside xaml code - it's dynamic). Also, I am looking for a way to see the error in code to log it.